# datepicker format now show month perfectly in ios swift 4.1?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

```
@objc func todatePickerDone(){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    toDateText.text = formatter.string(from: toDatePicker.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

The result show like this.

Coming todate here **23/49/2018**

Coming fromDate here **04/51/2017**

Comment: What do you mean by "solve this"? What do you expect?

Comment: month show live 49, 51 why

Comment: change your dateformat to this: `formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"`

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? The small `m` should be the placeholder for minutes

Comment: change your dateFormater from mm to MM. mm is for minute, not month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the format of Date Component first.

check this [website](http://nsdateformatter.com/) and compare with your date format.

In your example you had used `mm` which represent minute component.

and for month you need to `MM`.

See below other format for month.

1) For short text month i.e **Jun** - `MMM`

2) for full Month name i.e **June** - `MMMM`

**You solution**

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
toDateText.text = formatter.string(from: toDatePicker.date)
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `mm` that is used  for minute not for month. For month you need to use `MM`.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"      // use MM
let dt = formatter.string(from: Date())
print(dt)
```

**Solution**

```
@objc func todatePickerDone(){
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
  toDateText.text = formatter.string(from: toDatePicker.date)
  self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

For list of date parameter refer [this](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).